# Oracle DB+Weblogic in a single container

Tags: oracle, jboss, docker, weblogic, containers

I need to to install oracle 11 g along with a webserver like JBoss/Weblogic in a single docker container to facilitate an integrated production platform.I know that I can use two different containers and make them interact but that's not what I want.A single container with both Applications.How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Docker's mantra is one process in a container, but you can have several. You need to use some tool like supervisor http://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/ ,s6, daemontools or such

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for answering the question.I am new to the docker technology,started exploring it three days back.Do I need to write a script to do the required?Is there a tutorial available which can help me proceed further.
Thanks

Comment: Have you read the doc in my answer? See also this example https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_riak_service/ or this one http://blog.trifork.com/2014/03/11/using-supervisor-with-docker-to-manage-processes-supporting-image-inheritance/

Comment: Yes I've read the doc.I'm using ubuntu 14.04.While preparing the dockerfile.I don't knw how to decide what shall be the arguments  with the FROM and  MAINTAINER command.

Comment: MAINTAINER is optional, usually you put something like john doe <john.doe@mymail.com> FROM is highly relevant, select carefully your Linux (Debian, Ubuntu or any) check the Oracle compatibility guide for this